# Use MLModern as-is with LuaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, type1, mlmodern

The [mlmodern](https://ctan.org/pkg/mlmodern?lang=en) font is currently supplied only as Type-1, and works well with pdfLaTeX. However, I would like to use LuaLaTeX (specifically, I want to use the `tikz.graphdrawing` library, which requires Lua). Is there any way I can use the font with LuaTeX?

[This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/p4r53g/where_can_i_get_the_mlmodern_font_as_a_ttf_file/) contains a link to `.ttf` files of the font (apparently converted with FontForge). I suspect I will have an extremely long `\setmainfont{}` command to map all the font files correctly.

What can I do?

Comment: luatex can use exactly the same font as you used on pdftex, you don't have to use fontspec and a TrueType version

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I tried simply using `\usepackage{mlmodern}` and it didn't work at all (there was output, but no styles/weights whatsoever). Is there something additional I have to do?

Comment: You shouldn't use the package with lualatex,  the encodings don't fit.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well if you just want Lua for graph calculations and don't want Opentype fonts you can use legacy encodings to match the fonts. (I wouldn't do that, but you can:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understood the question so that the font for the whole document should be changed,  not only for some graph.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer perhaps I should have clarified: I wanted the document to be typeset in MLModern, and to compile said document (which contains `tikz.graphdrawing` code) using the LuaTeX engine, so that said TikZ code compiles successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave no example of your issue but using

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mlmodern}

\begin{document}

abc \textbf{abc} \textit{xyz} $f(x)$

\end{document}
```

with lualatex gives the same output as with pdflatex, with the lualatex terminal  showing ml fonts all being used:

[image]

```
$ lualatex bb458
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./bb458.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15>
 L3 programming layer <2021-11-12>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mlmodern/mlmodern.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mlmodern/t1mlmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)
(./bb458.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mlmodern/ot1mlmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mlmodern/omlmlmm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mlmodern/omsmlmsy.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mlmodern/omxmlmex.fd) [1{/usr/loc
al/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./bb458.aux))
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:35,3:4,4:1,5:28,6:2,7:64,8:4,9:18
{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-rm.enc}{/usr/local/te
xlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-mathit.enc}{/usr/local/texlive/2021
/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/public/mlmodern/mlmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts
/type1/public/mlmodern/mlmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/ty
pe1/public/mlmodern/mlmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/
public/mlmodern/mlmri10.pfb>
Output written on bb458.pdf (1 page, 35612 bytes).
Transcript written on bb458.log.
```

Comment: It turns out that I hadn't added `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, and that caused the typeface to fail to work. Thank you for this.

Comment: @SRSR333 you should always use T1 with pdflatex (otherwise it defaults to OT1 which is 7-bit and has no accented characters), normally you should use T1 with luatex as it prevents the use of opentype Unicode fonts, but as that's what you want here...)

Comment: I presume you meant '*shouldn't* use T1 with LuaTeX'... That said, I was aware of the necessity to use T1 in `pdflatex`. I also recall the rule about having T1 in the Unicode engines (Xe, LuaTeX) preventing Unicode from working properly, but I didn't realise I'd have to add it back in for MLModern... Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @SRSR333 sorry yes normally you shouldn't use T1 for luatex as the two main benefits of luatex are Lua and Unicode fonts but if you want the pdflatex fonts but use Lua, that's exactly what you need

Comment: fantastic. I was going to ask question on this. I also did not know I had to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` now it works.

Comment: @Nasser 9999 times out of 10000 using T1 encoding with luatex is the wrong thing to do. Are you _sure_ you are in that 1 in 10000 case?

Comment: That is what I thought.  But if I do not add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} the text  remain thin, but the math is bold as expected. I wanted both text and math to match. By adding \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} they both are bold now. Are you saying this is wrong to do? I am confused. Since that is what your answer says to do.

Comment: @Nasser I was answering a specific question with an unusual request to use exactly the same fonts in luatex as in pdftex. The chance that this answer applies to any normal document is very small, but don't ask questions as comments on old answers, make a new question if needed.

Comment: Great idea. I just made new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642816/how-to-make-text-boldness-match-math-when-using-lualatex-with-mlmodern-package