# How to make text boldness match math when using lualatex with mlmodern package?

Tags: fonts, luatex, mlmodern

I found about [mlmodern](https://ctan.org/pkg/mlmodern?lang=en) and I really like it as it makes CM font bolder and more clear.

But the surrounding text is still light and does not match.  I am using lualatex. What is the correct way to make both math and text same boldness?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mlmodern}

\begin{document}

This is another example. Text looks little thinner than math
\[
\sin x= 1 
\]    

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like the output to look like this

[image]

Which I can do by adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` before loading `mlmodern`. But since one is not supposed to use `fontenc` with lualatex, how else to achieve the above result without using `fontenc`?

TL 2022.

Comment: as far as I can see mlmodern is just intended for classic tex, you can use latin modern with fontspec options to alter the boldness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option, with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, is

```
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}
```

To load New Computer Modern Book for both text and math.  `\usepackage{newcomputermodern}` should also work.