# --- warning --- Couldn't find font `mlmsy8.htf' (char codes: 0--173) how to correct? TL 2022

Tags: fonts, tex4ht

I was compiling older source tree I have using TL 2022 on Ubuntu.

I noticed this warning, which I do not know where the source of it is, and how to correct it

```
[INFO]    htlatex: LaTeX call: dvilualatex --interaction=errorstopmode -jobname='index'  --interaction=batchmode -shell-escape '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\AddToHook{class/before}{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode nma_mathjax.cfg,mathjax,htm,fn-in,3,notoc*,p-width,charset=utf-8,charset=utf-8,html5.a.b.c.\input "\detokenize{index.tex}"'
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)
 system commands enabled.

[INFO]    mkutils:  mathjax,htm,fn-in,3,notoc*,p-width,charset=utf-8,html5,
[INFO]    mkutils: executing: tex4ht  -cunihtf -utf8 "index.dvi"
--- warning --- Couldn't find font `mlmsy8.htf' (char codes: 0--173)
```

I searched for this file `mlmsy8.htf` and can't find it. I do not even know which latex file is causing this to show in the source tree to correct it.

Any one can suggest how to correct this?  Why is this file missing?  I tried TL 2022 on two Linux Ubuntu systems, with same warning.

Sorry I do not have MWE, since I have no idea where this warning is coming from and if it is safe to just ignore it. It shows only when using tex4ht and not lualatex.

Comment: didn't you just switch from mlmodern to newcomputermodern for luatex? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/642816/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right. I disable mlmdern package when in tex4ht mode and now the warning is gone. I'll post this as answer in case someone make same mistake in future so to close this.

Comment: it is not hard to add Mlmodern font supprot to TeX4ht, as it seems that it uses the same encoding as Latin Modern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message means that the character mapping table for that font is missing, so the default table will be used instead. As the default table is based on Computer Modern, you shouldn't experience missing characters in your file. But you can experience missing formatting, which is also included in the mapping files.

Anyway, basic mapping for `mlmodern` can be added with these files:

`rm-mlm.htf`:

```
.rm-lm 
htfcss: rm-mlmbo  font-style: oblique;
htfcss: rm-mlmbx  font-weight: bold;
htfcss: rm-mlmbxi  font-style:italic; font-weight: bold;
htfcss: rm-mlmbxo  font-style: oblique; font-weight: bold;
htfcss: rm-mlmri  font-style:italic;
htfcss: rm-mlmro  font-style: oblique;
htfcss: rm-mlmss  font-family: sans-serif;
htfcss: rm-mlmssbo  font-family: sans-serif; font-style: oblique; font-weight: bold;
htfcss: rm-mlmssbx  font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
htfcss: rm-mlmssdc  font-family: sans-serif;
htfcss: rm-mlmssdo  font-family: sans-serif; font-style: oblique;
htfcss: rm-mlmsso  font-family: sans-serif; font-style: oblique;
htfcss: rm-mlmssq  font-family: sans-serif;
htfcss: rm-mlmssqbo  font-family: sans-serif; font-style: oblique; font-weight: bold;
htfcss: rm-mlmssqbx  font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
htfcss: rm-mlmssqo  font-family: sans-serif; font-style: oblique;
htfcss: rm-mlmcsc font-variant: small-caps;
```

The `.rm-lm` line means that it should use character mapping from `rm-lm.htf`. We can do this trick because they have the same characters.

You need also few other files:

`mlmex.htf`:

```
.cmex
```

`mlmmi.htf`:

```
.cmmi
htfcss: mlmmib font_weight:bold;
```

`mlmsy.htf`:

```
.plbsy
```

All of these files are copies of mapping files for Latin Modern, and reference other HTF files that contain actual character mapping.

Comment: I just a chance to try `mlmodern` with tex4ht. First, I am not sure how using different font with tex4ht actually works, since the font is set by me, in the .cfg file itself. But anyway, I found the following (I assume the files above are now in the official repository, since I no longer get warning after updating TL). I found bold fonts no longer work. Not big deal for me, since I do not load this package when using tex4ht, but thought to let you know. Here is a MWE and the command I use to compile it ....

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mlmodern}
\begin{document}
\underline{\textbf{Maple}} \textbf{[A]} 
Some of the \textbf{greatest} discoveries in science were made by accident.  \end{document}`  compiled using `make4ht  -ulm default -a debug foo.tex "mathjax,htm"` and looking at the HTML shows there is no bold text anywhere. Removing this package, now the text becomes bold again.  Again, this does not affect me, as I do not use `mlmoden` with tex4ht. This is just FYI. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser thanks for the report. You are right, I will update the font mapping files.